# Raspberry Pi - Nextcloud - Snap - stuck on making 'Read only Filesystem" writable

Tags: filesystem, raspberrypi

Installed nextcloud on Raspi with snap. 
Now I am stuck with editing the config.php file. 
Tried:

```
chomd 775 config.php
```

also tried

```
sudo chmod 775 config.php
```

It comes up:"changing permissions of 'config.php': Read-only file system"

Complete Path is: /snap/nextcloud/current/htdocs/config/config.php
Has anybody a tip how to change it into write permission? 
Thank you!

Comment: A read-only file system usually means something has gone wrong, and you need to `fsck` (file system check).  It could also be you've mounted it that way, but if it's your /, I'd suspect a `fsck`.  I'd remove the memory card & use a another device (probably a pc) to `fsck` the memory-card.

Comment: thank you! will try that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Snaps are mounted as read-only filesystems. Therefore none of the files under ´/snap/nextcloud/´ can be edited. Each snap does have a writable directory under ´/var/snap//current´. You might check there for the config.php.

However, snaps also have a native configuration system which nextcloud could be using. Try running ´snap get nextcloud´. If you see a list of configs, you probably want to set them there

Comment: Ah thank you! This one worked perfectly fine!!!

Answer (score 0):

Installing snap core worked for me.

```
sudo snap install core
```